# CSS in IE doesnt load

Tags: theming

CSS styles don't load in Internet Explorer (checked on version 9 and 7). They work locally, but not on the remote server. Do you have any idea?

**Edit**: It seems that compressing CSS inside "configuration >> performance" causes this problem. Is there a way to turn this feature for all browsers except IE?

Comment: Are you saying turning 'Optimize CSS files' *on* (on the admin/settings/performance page) causes this problem, or turning it *off* causes this problem?

Comment: @geerlingguy With turned this feature ON I have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does turning on CSS aggregation make your CSS work in IE?

If so, you may be coming up against the [31 CSS file limit in Internet Explorer](http://john.albin.net/css/ie-stylesheets-not-loading).

Someone has made a module that deals with this - [IE Unlimited CSS Loader](http://drupal.org/project/unlimited_css).

Comment: CSS aggregation cause this problem for sure so I turned it off. The module You provided is not compatible with Drupal 7 :(
In link You gave me I read thats not a problem in Drupal 7... But that's not true for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is copy the html.tpl.php template from modules/system/html.tpl.php to your themes templates directory, so sites/all/themes/your theme/templates and open it up.  In the head section add this tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" >
```

This tells Internet Explorer to specifically use the web standards incorporated into IE 8.  This means that basically for any version of Internet Explorer equal to 8 and above you'll have, at minimum, IE 8 viewing standards.  I had to do this same thing when using CSS aggregation.

BTW, you don't necessarily have to use version 8 as the base, if your site runs fine with 7 then I'd recommend going with 7.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the 32 stylesheet limit there's a 4095 selector per stylesheet limit. If you're encountering that issue with aggregation *on* then it's probably the selector limit.

I've gotten around this in the past by writing a page preprocess function to split up aggregated stylesheets into smaller chunks than IE can handle.